# Container with BoxDecoration Image Not Showing Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm beginner with flutter. I try to make like a banner image with boxdecoration so it can fit the width of the parent, and right below it is like search engine, but it's won't show in the demo device. I've tried to change the code but it's just get more confusing.
This is the code

```
Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
   child: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
         image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/pln.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
         ),
      ),
   ),
),
```

This is the
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRaVY.png)

I want to make it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk1kx.jpg)

And this is the full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
           title: SizedBox(
             height: 50,
             child: Image.network('assets/logo_pln.png'),
           )
        ),
        body: const MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/pln.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Masukkan ID Pelanggan',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text('Cari'),
            ),
          ),
        ]
    );
  }
}
class BannerImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BannerImage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/pln.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in appbar u used Image.network but u didn't pass url

Comment: `child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo_pln.png')),`
is it right? but the image in my question still did'nt show

Comment: do you want to add the image in the appbar

Comment: where do you want to show the banner

Comment: Right below the appbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving height to this container

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/pln.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),
```

This will work I think.